# My for loop isn't working

Tags: python, function, for-loop, input

- the program i have writen is meant to take the users input which is a integer then times it with the range of 1-10 so userinput x 1-10. however when i run my program an error occurs saying 'bool' is not iterable..
  im new to coding so please go easy <3

  Heres my code:

  And heres the error:
- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  loop()
  File "C:/Users/chemg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/loop1.py", line 6, in loop
  for numbers in number in range(1,10):
  TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
- this error occurs after the user enters a value

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this line up

```
for numbers in number in range(1,10):
```

```
range(1,10) => 1..10
number in range(1,10) => True/False, but what is 'number'? 0? So, 'False'
numbers in number in range(1,10) => Error!!! There are no 'numbers' in 'False'
```

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
for number in range(1,10):
    # do something
```

You also have an error later where you are trying to print 4 things, but only specified 3 in the `format()`.

```
print("Here it is {0}:\n {1} x {2} = {3}".format(number,add,name))
```

And you put `name` as `{2}`, so that would have printed something like

```
Here it is 1: 7 x James = ??
```

So, you can fix that by

```
add=int(input("Enter number and i will display the times table: "))
for number in range(1,10):
    print("{0} x {1} = {2}".format(add, number, add*number))
```

Comment: @erip Well, yeah :) But, `number = 0` was never needed.

Comment: @circket_007 this worked, but not in the way i intended. it seems to start of by multiplying say 7 by 1 then 7 by 2 but then it goes 14 by 3 then 42 by 4?

Comment: @JamesW That's because that's what you tell it to do. `add= add*number`.

Comment: @erip surely it would go 7x1, 7x2, 7x3 etc?

Comment: Keep track of your `add` variable. You're changing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop number is a single variable ,not a iterable ,and it is an invalid syntax , so replace ur code with the below and
No need to write number=0,

```
def loop():
    name=input("Enter name: ").capitalize()
    print("Hey {0}".format(name))
    add=int(input("Enter number and i will display the times table: "))
    for number in range(1,11): # last value is not included so to iterate up to 10 write 11
        product= add*number
        print(" {1} x {2} = {3} \n ".format(number,add,product))
```

Answer (score 1):

You also probably don't want to store the result of the multiplication into 'add' because for each iteration of the loop, 'add' will be the value from the previous iteration rather than what the user entered which doesn't produce a multiplication table.  In fact all your results will be 0 for the below:

```
for number in range(10):
    print('{0} * {1}'.format(add, number))
    add = add*number
    print("Result:{0}".format(add))
```

Test in your cli with range(1,10) as you had in your code originally so it starts with 1 instead of 0 and you will see the results aren't a multiplication table:

```
for number in range(1,10):
    print('{0} * {1}'.format(add, number))
    add = add * number
    print(add)
```

Here is a complete version with all the changes:

```
def loop():
    name=input("Enter name: ").capitalize()
    print("Hey {0}".format(name))
    add=int(input("Enter number and i will display the times table: "))
    for number in range(1,10):
        product = add * number
        print("Here it is {0}:\n {1} x {2} = {3}".format(name,add,number,product))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Ok i seemed to have done it. its probably what the answers put, but this is what i came up with

  ```
  def loop():
      numbers=int(input("Enter a number: "))
      add=numbers
      for number in range(1,900000000000):
          numbers= add*number
          print("{0} x {2} = {1}".format(add,numbers,number))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`number in range(1,10)` is being evaluated to `False` (because 0 isn't in `range(1,10)`, so `for numbers in False` is causing problems.

You probably just want `for number in range(1,10):`.